How can I use the FortiWeb v2.0 API in order to upload an SSL certificate and private key from script?
I think I'm going crazy with this one.
I'm trying to automate (with a python script) the mechanical task of renewing and uploading all of our SSL certificates in our FortiWeb proxy (the version is 7.0.6).
I managed to automate the part where I download from SSL store the certificates.
Now I wish to upload all of my locally saved certificates and keys onto the proxy.
And here is where the fun begins.
Here is the API documentation: https://fndn.fortinet.net/index.php?/fortiapi/939-fortiweb/2535/939/system/
The URL of the request:
https://<IP-ADDRESS>:<PORT>/api/v2.0/cmdb/system/certificate.local
The header of the request:
header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": authToken
    }


The body of the request:
data = {
        "data": {
            "name": "test_cert",
            "type": "certificate",
            "status": "ok",
            "comment": "",
            "flag": 0,
            "is-hsm": "no",
            "partition-number": "",
            "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- <PEM CERTIFICATE> ----END CERTIFICATE----",
            "private-key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- <PEM KEY> -----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
            "passwd": ""
        }
    }


The POST request: requests.post(URL, json=data, headers=header, verify=False)
Since the official documentation only indicates that the value corresponding the "certificate" and "private-key" keys is a string in PEM format, i've simply copied and pasted the value of the .crt file and .key file.
However i get this error:
{ "results": { "errcode": -7721: Invalid certificate } }
I can assure that the certificate is valid.
Also, the GET method works as intended: it returns all the already uploaded certificates.
I tried these combinations.

Firstly i tried editing the certificate file removing all of the newlines.
I tried removing the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" lines
I tried encoding the certificate both with and without the previous lines and both using the tool at www.base64encode.org and with the code with open("certfile.crt", "rb") as read: cert = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(read.read(-1)).decode()
I tried to use the URL found in the Chrome web debugging tools while manually uploading a certificate: https://<IP-ADDRESS>:<PORT>/api/v2.0/system/certificate.local.import_certificate

I always get an "error 500 Internal server error" with errcode: -7721 or -651
Is there something else i could try?
Thank you very much.

The forti support can help you, I used the code below. It's in php, but you can do this like:
$call="https://$hostname/api/v2.0/system/certificate.local.import_certificate";
$cert_upload_response=do_curl_pemcert_upload($api_key,$call,"/tmp/".$cert_filename,"/tmp/".$key_filename,$cert_name);
  $status=json_decode($cert_upload_response);

function do_curl_pemcert_upload($apikey,$call,$cfile,$kfile,$cname)
{
  var_dump($cfile);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $call);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  $cfile = new CURLFile(realpath($cfile),"application/octet-stream",$cname);

  $post = array(
        'type' => 'intermediate-certificate',
        'certificateFile' => $cfile,

  );
  if ($kfile)
  {
    $kfile = new CURLFile(realpath($kfile),"application/octet-stream",$cname);
    $post['keyFile']=$kfile;
  }
  // print_r($post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = 'Authorization: '.$apikey;
  $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
  $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result;
}

